# Lots of memory errors trying to reimplement the getline function

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, valgrind

I'm trying to re-implement the function getline and I'm facing a lot of memory errors during execution. I hope someone can help me solve them and explain why. Here is a link for the code:

https://pastebin.com/qFzHdeL8

#### `getline.c`

```c
/*********** _getline.c ***************/
#include "_getline.h"

char *_getline(const int fd)
{
    ssize_t r = 0;
    char *file_content = malloc(sizeof(char) * READ_SIZE);
    char *empty = malloc(sizeof(char));
    char *line;
    static char *relay_buffer;
    static int begin = 0;
    int end;

    memset(empty, '\0', 1);
    r = read(fd, file_content, READ_SIZE);
    /* keep reading the file content and append to relay_buffer */
    /* until a '\n' is found */
    while (strchr(file_content, '\n') == NULL && r != 0)
    {
        if (relay_buffer == NULL)
        {
            relay_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * r);
            memcpy(relay_buffer, file_content, r);
        }
        else
        {
            relay_buffer = realloc(relay_buffer, strlen(relay_buffer) + r);
            strcat(relay_buffer, file_content);
        }
        r = read(fd, file_content, READ_SIZE);
    }
    /* Reaching end of file */
    if (r == 0)
    {
        /* check if relay_buffer still contains chars */
        if (relay_buffer != NULL)
        {
            if (begin >= (int)strlen(relay_buffer))
            {
                return NULL;
            }
            /* parse for lines */
            if (relay_buffer[begin] == '\n')
            {
                begin++;
                return empty;
            }
            end = begin;
            while (*(relay_buffer + end) != '\n' && end <= (int)strlen(relay_buffer))
            {
                end++;
            }
            line = malloc(sizeof(char) * (end + 1 - begin));
            strncpy(line, relay_buffer + begin, end - begin);
            begin = end + 1;
            return (line);
        }
        return (NULL);
    }
    /* add file content to relay_buffer */
    if (relay_buffer == NULL)
    {
        relay_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * r);
        memcpy(relay_buffer, file_content, r);
    }
    else
    {
        relay_buffer = realloc(relay_buffer, r + strlen(relay_buffer));
        strcat(relay_buffer, file_content);
    }
    /* parse relay buffer to extract line */
    if (relay_buffer[begin] == '\n')
    {
        begin++;
        return empty;
    }
    end = begin;
    while (*(relay_buffer + end) != '\n')
    {
        end++;
    }
    line = malloc(sizeof(char) * (end - begin) + 1);
    strncpy(line, relay_buffer + begin, end - begin);
    line[end + 1] = '\0';
    begin = end + 1;
    return (line);
}
```

#### `main.c`

```c
/************ main.c ********************/
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "_getline.h"

/**
 * main - entry point.
 *
 * Return: always 0.
 */
int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    char *line;

    fd = open("lorem.txt", 0);
    while ((line = _getline(fd)))
    {
        printf("%s\n", line);
        free(line);
    }
    close(fd);
    return (0);
}
```

#### `lorem.txt`

```
/**************** lorem.txt *****************/
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
It has survived not only five centuries,
but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
remaining essentially unchanged.
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

#### `getline.h`

```c
/******************** getline.h *****************/
#ifndef _GETLINE_H
#define _GETLINE_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define READ_SIZE 10

char *_getline(const int fd);

#endif
```

My idea is to create a static variable called `relay_buffer` each time `read()` get data from the file it will be appended to `relay_buffer` until the read content contains a `\n`.
Then I will extract the data between the `begin` index and the position of the new line and copy it to a null-terminated variable `line`. The index `begin` is static so I could keep track of where I start extracting again.
My current output is:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,rem
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
It has survived not only five centuries,
but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The output and errors vary with the number of lines; sometimes I get junk output.

Using `valgrind`, I get a lot of invalid reads and writes, even if the output is clean.

Comment: Please post the code in the question.  Links to pastebin etc are not acceptable on SO.

Comment: You say "reimplementing `getline` function", but code defines `_getline` and doesn't have the same interface as the POSIX function [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).  Which `getline()` are you reimplementing?  The use of any `static` variable is immediately suspect.

Comment: Valgrind is telling you where there are problems. Fix the problems it identifies. Invalid reads and writes are serious problems and one or more of those ends up triggering the `realloc()` failure. Make sure you are compiling and linking with the `-g` flag to get the line numbers where the trouble occurs.

Comment: First `strchr(file_content, ...`: your buffer is not null terminated. Did you even try to debug this? Actually you don't care at all that your strings __must__ be terminated by a null character.

Comment: Your code only works if you only ever pass one fd to the function because `static char *relay_buffer`. You should do like stdio and create a structure that contains the fd and the buffer.

Comment: You should be able to find some free implementations of the POSIX `getline` and `getdelim` functions online. They return the POSIX type `ssize_t` which is not part of the C standard.